# Problemas ocultar/mostrar a4j commandobutton

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

Tengo un "a4j commandButton" que desde un combo que tiene el siguiente event change lo intento actualizar para que pase a verse en pantalla:

```
<a4j:ajax render="modelNameNew, prueba " event="change" execute="@this" />

<a4j:commandButton id="prueba" action="..." oncomplete="..." rendered="#{!managedBean.Boolean}" />
```

Resulta que no se actualiza y no actualiza el resto de elementos que hay detras de ese punto en la pantalla, sin embargo elementos anteriores como el inputext de abajo si se actualizan.

```
<h:inputText id="modelNameNew" disabled="#{managedBean.Boolean}" />
```

En otras pantallas tengo la misma casuística y cero problemas, se actualiza todo perfectamente, los input se habilitan y los botones aparecen.

¿Que puede hacer que el botón no este tirando bien en este caso?. Decir que si en lugar de rendered, uso la etiqueta disabled, no hay ningún problema, se habilita y deshabilita el botón en consecuencia.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en que estás confundiendo el concepto de los atributos `rendered` y `disabled` de JSF.

`rendered` es un atributo propio de JSF. Significa que el componente no será renderizado, por ende el componente no formará parte del `TreeView` que arma JSF detrás de las escenas, lo que significa que el componente no puede ser utilizado para obtener su data o editarlo. Esto se puede comprobar simplemente con ver el HTML generado, verás que tu componente no existe, al no existir no se le puede aplicar ninguna funcionalidad vía javascript o similar. Por ello que `<a4j:ajax render="modelNameNew, prueba " event="change" execute="@this" />` falla.

`disabled` es un atributo de HTML. Significa que el componente está deshabilitado o no. Al enviar los datos del formulario al servidor, por defecto los datos de los componentes que estén deshabilitados no serán enviados al servidor. Sin embargo, estos componentes sí se encuentran renderizados y se puede acceder a ellos vía JavaScript. Por ello que `<a4j:ajax render="modelNameNew, prueba " event="change" execute="@this" />` funciona correctamente para este componente.

El problema con el uso de `rendered` es muy común cuando se trabaja con JSF. La solución es utilizar un `UIContainer` sobre el componente que tiene el atributo `rendered` y re-renderizar el `UIContainer` en lugar de re-renderizar el componente en cuestión. En código se entiende mejor:

```
<!-- Se indica que se renderizará pruebaContainer, no prueba -->
<a4j:ajax render="modelNameNew, pruebaContainer" event="change" execute="@this" />
<!--
    Se crea un componente UIContainer que sirva como wrapper al componente a re-renderizar con el atributo rendered.
    En este caso, utilizaré un h:panelGroup y le pondré el id pruebaContainer
-->
<h:panelGroup id="pruebaContainer">
    <!-- Dentro del UIContainer colocamos el componente que necesita ser re-renderizado -->
    <a4j:commandButton id="prueba" action="..." oncomplete="..." rendered="#{!managedBean.Boolean}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: El problema no era que estuviese confundiendo conceptos que ya conocía, como comentas. No obstante, con tu comentario pude acabar solucionandolo refrescando un elemento que contenia el botón. en lugar del botón directamente.

Comment: Si no los confundieras hubieras entendido el problema desde el inicio y no habrías lanzado la pregunta...

Comment: Ni que la pregunta fuera cual es la diferencia entre rendered y disabled.

Comment: Básicamente esa es la pregunta asociado con el atributo render de ajax.